# Julia - not able to capture looped back UDP packets in Wireshark

Tags: networking, udp, julia, wireshark

I have a UDP sender program here:

```
# UDPSender.jl
using Sockets
sock = UDPSocket()
bind(sock,IPv4(200,120,1,1),1025)

data = [0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b, 0xb8, 0x64, 0x00]

send(sock,ip"200.120.1.1", 11028,data)
```

and the UDP listener here:

```
# UDPListener.jl
using Sockets
s = Sockets.UDPSocket()
Sockets.bind(s, ip"200.120.1.1", 11028)
while true
    hostport, packet = Sockets.recvfrom(s)
      println(packet)
end
```

When both files are run in seperate Julia command lines,
The statement `println(packet)` in UDPListener.jl is able to print data in the command line.
But these packets are not captured by Wireshark.

Why Wireshark is not able to display the packets?

OS: Windows 10 64 bit. LAN is looped back

NB : asked the same qn to julia discourse site, not yet approved.

Comment: Have you tried doing similar in a different language? Is this specific to Julia’s network stack or is this typical of loopback UDP traffic in general?

Comment: @StefanKarpinski In Matlab this kind of code was working with broadcast ip address 255.255.255.255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to change the destination ip address to 255.255.255.255 [broadcasting?]

```
send(sock,ip"255.255.255.255", 11028,data)
```

permission denied message came.

Then I changed ip address to 200.120.1.255 [multicasting?]

```
send(sock,ip"200.120.1.255", 11028,data)
```

then Wireshark is able to capture the packets.